# Is 髪隠し a pun on 神隠し?

Tags: etymology, puns

[image: A 髪隠し]

The above is a picture of a piece of cloth that is often worn on the head as part of a 死に装束. I have most commonly seen it referred to as a 天冠, but have also seen it referred to as a 髪隠し.

Did the name 髪隠し originate as a pun on 神隠し (in the sense of "spiriting away"), which is a homophone? Both terms have to do with death in a sense, and a 天冠 doesn't actually do that good a job of 隠すing the 髪 (so it doesn't seem like a particularly good choice of name), so I was curious.

Comment: probably there is no relationship between the two words... though in 千と千尋の神隠し there is an interesting example

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a pun on 神隠し。

Although, I've learned that the the word "kami" (as in 神、髪、上）all came from a common ancestry word meaning something that is higher, or more honerable. So the words themselves are  related in that sense.

Comment: The claim that 神 and 上 are the same word is easily refuted by 上代特殊仮名遣い evidence: the み in 上 is 甲類, the み in 神 is 乙類.